# how to get the max and min data of each month in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i have data like that:

```
{
    "_id" : "objid", //document id
  "date" : new Date("2015/01/01 00:00:00"),
  "value" : 14
 },
...
 {
  "_id" : "objid",
  "date" : new Date("2015/01/30 00:00:00"),
  "value" : 25
 },
 {
  "_id" : "objid",
  "date" : new Date("2015/02/01 00:00:00"),
  "value" : 211
 },
 {
  "_id" : "objid",
  "date" : new Date("2015/02/15 00:00:00"),
  "value" : 200
 }
...
```

now i want to group by month to get the max time's data and min time's data.
eg: in month "2015-01" the max time is 2015/01/30,so the value=25 is what i want to get.

if use aggregate i only can get the time,how to get the value

```
{
"$match": {
    "date": {
        "$gte":  new Date("2014-12-31T16:00:00.000Z"),
        "$lt": new Date("2015-12-31T16:00:00.000Z")
    }
  }
},
{
"$group": {
    "_id": {
        "month":{
            "$month" : "$date"
        }
    },
    "minDate":{
        "$min": "$date",
    },
    "maxDate":{
        "$max": "$date"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How come _id field is same for all the documents?

Comment: hi,it is only a simple describe,not real data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The strategy is to do a sort on date field and while grouping pop out the last value,

```
{
"$match": {
    "date": {
        "$gte":  new Date("2014-12-31T16:00:00.000Z"),
        "$lt": new Date("2015-12-31T16:00:00.000Z")
    }
  }
},
{
"$sort": {
   "date": 1
  }
},
{
"$group": {
    "_id": {
        "month":{
            "$month" : "$date"
        }
    },
    "minDate":{
        "$min": "$date",
    },
    "maxDate":{
        "$max": "$date"
    },
    "value":{
        "$last": "$value"
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of `"min"` and `"max"` you can also use `"first"` and `"last"` respectively, as you are sorting the documents based on date.